# Class constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm a beginner to c++ so there are a lot of things quite not clear in my mind.

I have this code I need to write and in a class I make a constructor.
However, I don't need any parameters because I read from a file-stream *inside* the constructor. So my questions are:

1.Can I make a constructor like this:

```
class myClass {
private:
  string title;
  string organizer;
public:
  myClass() {
    title = stringRead();
    organizer = stringRead();
  }
}
```

where stringRead() is a function I have written to read from my file??

2.How do I call it afterwards when I need it? I know that the default constructror is being called like that:

```
myClass A;
A = myClass();
```

Is it the same?

3.If I have a pointer, how do I call the constructor again? This doesn't seem like it should be right...

```
myClass *B;
B = myClass();
```

Thanks in advance! =D

Comment: Useful read: see Constructors section at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)  This constructor will work but you should favor using an initialization list (assuming `stringRead()` isn't a member function of `myClass`

```
class myClass {
private:
  string title;
  string organizer;
public:
  myClass() 
    : title(stringRead()),
      organizer(stringRead())
  { }
};
```

2)  `myClass A;` is what you should be doing.  You could alternatively have `auto A = myClass();` which, after optimizations, will be the same thing.  Without optimizations a temporary will be constructed, and then `A` will be move constructed from it, so this won't work with unmovable objects (your object is movable)

3) If you want to use a raw pointer then you would use

```
myClass *ptr = new myClass;
// bunch of code
delete ptr;
```

However, you'd be better using a smart pointer to control its lifetime.  This way you won't need to manually delete

```
std::unique_ptr<myClass> ptr(new myClass);
```

or make_unique in c++14

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<myClass>();
```

And of course use a `shared_ptr` if you have shared ownership

Comment: about 2: I have a class in a class so there I have to write `class myClass1: private: myClass2 element;  public: myClass1() { /*call constructor of myClass2*/ }`

Comment: check it again. I hit 'enter' by mistake before finishing writing. =]

Comment: @Anina7 that doesn't parse.  Are you trying to inherit or you have a `myClass2` data member?  In either case you'd still use the initialization list syntax for your constructor but the name will vary.

Comment: probably: `myClass1() : myClass2(/* ctor args */) { }`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's OK to assign the value returned by a function to a member of a class.

You can initialize it as you suggested (with `myClass A;`)

When you use pointers, you need `myClass *k=new myClass();`. You should remember to delete the object you created with `delete k;`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your constructor is fine, so long as the functions used within it are globals or static functions of this or another class.
2. myClass A; will invoke the constructor you have written.
3. To use a pointer, you need B = new myClass(). That will also call the same constructor. Don't forget to delete B at some point else you'll leak memory.

Do bear in mind that if an exception is thrown in a constructor then the destructor is not called.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can, but it might not be the best approach. Reading from input can fail, failure in a constructor is often a non-recoverable event you'll want to handle. A good approach is reading the values outside the costructor, handling errors and calling the constructor only when you have "everything ready". Like this:

   ```
   class myClass {
   private:
   string _title;
   string _organizer;
   public:
     myClass(const string &title, const string &organizer) {
       _title = title;
       _organizer = organizer;
   }
   ```

   or, by using a more idiomatic C++ initializer list:

   ```
   class myClass {
   private:
   string _title;
   string _organizer;
   public:
     myClass(const string &title, const string &organizer):
       _title(title), _organizer(organizer) {}
   }
   ```

   and then, somewhere else:

   ```
   string title = stringRead();
   string organizer = stringRead();
   myClass A(title, organizer);
   ```
2. No, in this snippet:

   ```
   myClass A;
   A = myClass();
   ```

   two different things happen: at line 1 the default constructor is called; at line 2, a temporary object is constructed (again, by calling the default constructor) and then assigned to `A` using the (rval for C++11) copy operator. This expression:

   ```
   myClass A;
   ```

   calls the default constructor. If you have parameters:

   ```
   myClass A(title, organizer);
   ```
3. Nope, this does not even work. A pointer is not an object, you have to *allocate* the object. At that point, you can get a pointer to it:

   ```
   myClass A;
   myClass *B = &A;
   ```

   you could also resort to dynamic allocation:

   ```
   myClass *B = new myClass;
   ```

   in this case, either remember to call `delete B` somewhere else or wrap `B` in a smart pointer:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<myClass> B(new myClass());
   ```

Comment: your constructor has added leading underscores on the data members, and it is a java style constructor.  You should use an initialization list

Comment: @RyanHaining the initializer list is certainly more idiomatic, but it might not be clear to a true beginner like OP is. Anyway, I added both.